# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT Max

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, declare

im getting this error from this query in mysql

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT Max([end])
> FROM   #dates);  WITH cte      AS' at line 1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bugs (id int, open_date DATETIME, close_date DATETIME, severity int);
INSERT INTO bugs VALUES (0, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-03',3), (1,'2012-01-03', '2012-01-07',1), 
(2,'2012-01-01', '2012-01-05',3), (2,'2012-01-01', '2012-01-05',3), (2,'2012-01-01', '2012-01-05',3);

DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT Max([end]) FROM   #dates);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT NAME,
                open_date,
                [close_date]
         FROM   #dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NAME,
                Dateadd(day, 1, open_date,),
                Dateadd(day, 1, open_date,)
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  open_date < @maxdate)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to run MS SQL Server code on MySQL?!?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer to the duplicate question.